# Opening Eclipse Android maven project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I need to open Eclipse Maven project in Android Studio. I have several linked folders. [image]

The main logic of project (MainActivity and other classes) is in folder EU-GEN.view and app use some libraries/classes from other folders like maps, library etc. How to correctly open hole project in Android Studio?

Comment: I struggled with this for a long time, I gave Up and manually imported it by recreating the classes and copy the code over

Comment: I don't know where which class is used. For exampe, if main program or some class from main folder use some functions or libs from maps folder?! 
Should the whole structure be the same?

Comment: wait i am an idiot https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate, just use the import project in android studio

Comment: Will grandle solve all the problems correctly?

Comment: Yes, the project MIGHT need some minor tweaks but it will work

Comment: Just one question bro, 
I need to import all folders separately: maps, appcompat_v7, library... and main folder EU-GEN.view. Will everything be properly connected in the project in Android Studio?

Comment: import the folder that the project is stored in

Comment: The entire project folder cannot be loaded for some reason but I'll handle it myself. thank you brother